# Changing Artifact Id and Group Id of a Maven project from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is there a convenient way to change the **Artifact Id** and **Group Id** of a Maven project from Eclipse?  Of course there appears to be a brute-force way to do this:

1. Close the project, if open
2. Rename the project root to the new Artifact Id
3. Edit `.project`, `pom.xml` and `pom.properties` files to replace the old Artifact Id with the new Artifact Id
4. Change the sub-directory structure under `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` to conform to the new Group Id
5. Import back into Eclipse

Comment: Only change the information in `pom.xml` and remove `.project`, `.classpath` and `.settings`..which should be ignored by your version control anyway....The package might be changed but it's not really needed. Order of doing: First change groupId / artifactId in `pom.xml` remove project from eclipse workspace; remove Eclipse files and reimport project and refactor the package structure via refactoring of Eclipse.